# Webpack + Babel: ERROR: Preset files are not allowed to export objects

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I am new to VueJS and I am working on a VueJS app. I am getting a frustrating error when running build cmd: Preset files are not allowed to export objects.

Can anyone look at my configuration please and help me get this working? I am trying to get my app running in IE11. Currently it is showing blank pages with no useful errors.

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "basscss": "^8.0.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.9",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.11.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0"
  },
```

My .babelrc file is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
      }],
      "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
  }
```

My webpack.base.conf.js is

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
    ]
  }
```

and my main.js file includes

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import 'es6-promise/auto'
```